# AngularJS - access scope in directive from controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, scope, directive

I'm using the Angular UI Pagination angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

In this is a useful number I need to access: totalItems

```
.directive('pagination', ['$parse', 'paginationConfig', function($parse, config) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            page: '=',
            totalItems: '=',
            onSelectPage:' &'
        },
        controller: 'PaginationController',
        templateUrl: 'template/pagination/pagination.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, paginationCtrl) {
```

How can I access this from my controller? I have tried `$scope.totalItems` but nothing happens. No errors.

If I watch totalItems within the directive, it returns the correct value, but like I've said, I need to access it from the controller. Possibly also within the HTML itself.

Thanks

Comment: can you show the markup `<div pagination ..` ? and also the controller?

Comment: Hi. It's pretty much this http://plnkr.co/edit/s9qOG6RA3fDROn0aaJ0W?p=info  but I'm linking to the UI pagination directive and controller locally. Plunker is messing about and I can't save at the moment.

Comment: I notice that the directive above actually has its own Controller. This is a different controller to the one I've made. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Are you injecting a controller to this directive or you have a controller on the outer scope?

Comment: Unless bootstrap is doing something (you have to include ui.bootstrap when declaring the module) then I'm not explicitly doing it.